# FLOT - Fluid / Dynamic Charts - PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, flot

I am trying to Plot a Graph with FLOT but I cant get my head around how to get make it Dynamic with multiple series.

I am trying to get Race Data , Eg Laps and Time as the Graph x and y, but also trying to get the Race ID as a new series line for each Rider.

I have tried it at a Loop for each RaceID, and I have tried it as a multidimensional array, But I cant get my head around how to get it formatted to how  FLOT wants it.

I can get it to work with 1 Rider:

```
 $GetLapData = mysql_Query("SELECT LapData.*, u.RaceID
 FROM `LapData`
 left join User as u on LapData.TagID = u.TagID
 Where LapData.EventID = '$EventID'
 and LapData.RaceNameID = '$RaceNameID'
 and LapData.TagID = '$RacingNumber'
 ORDER BY `LapData`.`LapNumber` ASC");

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($GetLapData))
            {
                            $dataset1[] = array($row['LapNumber'],$row['LapTimeinSeconds']);
            }
```

and then plot the single Data Set

```
$(function() {
    var d1 = <?php echo json_encode($dataset1) ?>;
    $.plot("#placeholder", [ d1 ]);
});
```

Any Ideas on making it all riders for the Race would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tough question to answer without seeing your database scheme, but I'll give it a shot.

First, let's modify your SQL statement.  I'm guessing that this part `and LapData.TagID = '$RacingNumber'` is what subset's it down to a single rider?  Also, what's the purpose of the join, do you want the rider's name from there or some other identifier?  I've left it but if you aren't using it, it's a waste...

```
$GetLapData = mysql_Query("SELECT LapData.TagID, LapData.LapNumber, LapData.LapTimeInSeconds
   FROM LapData
   LEFT JOIN User AS u ON LapData.TagID = u.TagID
   WHERE LapData.EventID = '$EventID'
   ANDLapData.RaceNameID = '$RaceNameID'
   AND LapData.TagID = '$RacingNumber'
   ORDER BY LapData.TagID, LapData.LapNumber ASC");
```

---

```
$allSeries = array(); // our "return value"
$currentSeries = null; // some temp variables
$currentRider = null;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($GetLapData))
{
    $loopRider = $row['TagID']; // get rider for this database row
    if ($currentRider === null || $loopRider != $currentRider) // if first loop or new rider
    { 
        if ($currentSeries !== null)
        {
            $allSeries[] = $currentSeries; // we have a new rider push the last one to our return array
        }
        $currentSeries = array(); // this is first loop or new rider, re-init current series
        $currentSeries["label"] = $loopRider;
        $currentSeries["data"] = array();
    }
    $currentSeries["data"][] = array($row['LapNumber'],$row['LapTimeinSeconds']); //push row data into object
}
$allSeries[] = $currentSeries; // last rider's data push
```

In the end, `allSeries` is an array of associative arrays per flots [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format).

Mainly:

```
$allSeries = [{
    "label" = "tag1",
    "data" = [[0,12],[1,45],[2,454]]
},{
    "label" = "tag2",
    "data" = [[0,122],[1,415],[2,464]]
}]
```

After you Json encode this, the call is:

```
$.plot("#placeholder", allSeries);
```

*My Standard PHP disclaimer, I'm not a PHP programmer, I've never used it and never ever want to use it.  All the above code was peiced together from quickly reading the documentation and is untested.*

Comment: Hey Mark, Thanks heaps for your response, We are close but no banana... The output isn't looping correctly, It seems to be creating a new array for each line and not grouping it :(

Comment: Hi Mark, Missed a line:  $currentRider = $loopRider; once i got that in under the final current series, worked a treat.. much appreciated